# Is it Bad Practice to Call Methods in Locks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, backgroundworker

I'm using a background worker in my code that calls several functions once it's done doing work.

In these functions there are some private variables that are also used by the background worker (albeit they are accessed AFTER work is complete).

For instance,

```
        private void Work_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Handle_OnProgressBarCompleted();
            ParseDataFromXml();
            AddTabsWithDataGridViewToTabControl();
        }
```

Within most of these functions, there is a lock to protect private variables from being accessed by another thread. For instance, in ParseDataFromXml()

```
        private void ParseDataFromXml()
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                RiskLimitsConfigColl = _riskLimitXmlReader.GetRiskLimitsConfigurations(_filePath);
                var riskLimitValidationData = new RiskLimitValidationData(RiskLimitsConfigColl);
                Dataset = riskLimitValidationData.GetData();
                RiskLimitsConfigColl = riskLimitValidationData.GetRiskLimits();
                CommonConfigurations();
            }
        }
```

The amount of locks I'm using to protect my private variables are becoming unruly, and I feel like I'm spraying locks around my code without understanding where they should be (every private variable is in a lock statement).

My question is: Is it bad practice to include another function call in a lock statement? If `CommonConfigurations` in `ParseDataFromXML` had a lock statement inside of it, would I deadlock? What should be my best path forward when using lock statements?

I read [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx) that

> Exclusive locking is used to ensure that only one thread can enter particular sections of code at a time.

So I'm assuming I need to look for functions that are referenced by both threads and use locks there.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't say "it is good" or "it is bad" There might be specific scenarios and cases that the same logic could be considered as "bad practice" or "best practice".

Microsoft states that the lock keyword ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If another thread tries to enter a locked code, it will wait, block, until the object is released.

But in general, not specific to your case, there is *usually* a problem with threading when you use locks..

Lock-based resource protection and thread/process synchronization have many disadvantages and some of them are :

- They cause blocking, which means some threads/processes have to wait
  until a lock (or a whole set of locks) is released.
- Lock handling adds overhead for each access to a resource, even when
  the chances for collision are very rare. (However, any chance for
  such collisions is a race condition).
- Lock contention limits scalability and adds complexity.
- Priority Inversion High priority threads/processes cannot proceed, if
  a low priority thread/process is holding the common lock.
- Convoying. All other threads have to wait, if a thread holding a lock
  is descheduled due to a time-slice interrupt or page fault.
- Hard to debug: Bugs associated with locks are time dependent. They
  are extremely hard to replicate.

Answer (score 1):

The [`BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted) event runs in the UI thread, so you probably don't need to lock anything. Just make sure that you set the result of the background operation to the [`DoWorkEventArgs.Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.result) property, and then receive the same result in the UI thread from the [`RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.result) property. In other words avoid passing data directly from the one thread to the other by using shared fields.

A general advice about locking is to either do it correctly or not do it at all. If you decide that you have shared state which must by protected by a lock, then **every** access to this state must be protected by the same lock. Not a single read or write must be left unprotected. Sprinkling locks here and there to make things "safer", is as good as not having any locks at all. Your code is either thread-safe, or it's not.

Another general advice is to hold a lock for the shortest duration possible. Ideally a lock should protect an operation consisting of no more than a few dozen CPU instructions. The total duration between acquiring and releasing the lock should be measured in nanoseconds. If you routinely find yourself locking around database calls or other similar lengthy operations, you are probably doing something wrong.

My personal suggestion is to consider scraping the old-fashioned `BackgroundWorker` approach altogether in favor of the modern and powerful [async-await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) technology. By using async-await you can have all your code in one place, instead of being scattered in various event handlers. Here is an example:

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string xmlPath = GetPath();
    Task<XmlDocument> task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Start loading the document in a background thread
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xmlPath);
        return doc;
    });

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = await task; // Wait for the completion without blocking the UI

    // We are back in the UI thread again
    Handle_OnProgressBarCompleted();
    var data = ParseDataFromXml(xmlDoc);
    AddTabsWithDataGridViewToTabControl(data);
}
```

For reporting the progress of an asynchronous operation look [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/).